# Create team link in Profile edit broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

In profile edit. When clicked on blank Title box. Shows **You haven't joined any teams yet. Would you like to create one?**. But When clicked. Goes to `http://stackoverflow.com/teams/create` and says `Page Not Found`

Comment: Can confirm replication!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the link being displayed in the first place, and than failing in a check on the teams page. The link won't render anymore if you can't create teams (and you'd consequently get a 404 on that URL).

The changes will be live with the next build (build rev `2016.5.3.3532` on SO).